# Javascript window pop up and redirect back to homepage (Node.js | react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a site where I have used Facebook and google authentication and also oAuth2.0 library. But currently when I click the google or facebook login button then a redirection is happening in same page. But I want something like pinterest, a small pop up window will occur and then after login and token generation the popup will close and the main page will redirect to homepage. How to do so?

Current try:

```
 const googleAuth = () => {
    
    var gWin = window.open(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/google`, "Google login", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
    if(gName !== null){
     
       gWin.close();

    }

     window.location.href = "/courses";
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```